# EF Core unable to translate multiple Like query

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a DbSet Persons and string[] Names
and I am trying to query by multiple names using Like, ex:

```
db.Where(o => Names.Any(p => EF.Functions.Like(o.Name, p)))
```

and I keep getting "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()"

I want to execute this on sql server so I can't evaluate it. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: I was searching for an answer and I found a way, just don't know why EF doesn't support this natively.
[link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834)

Comment: It would have to translate an array of strings into some sort of SQL. EF6 had a rather clumsy (though the only) way to do that. Which wasn't scalable. They decided not to support it in EF core among many other things.

Comment: You can use a predicate builder to convert the strings into chained *or* (`||`) predicates.